# Both bibliography and citations are not showing up in the text using Tekmaker

Tags: bibliographies, citing, lists

I have tried all the solutions found online but nothing helped. Infact the same bib file worked well for the other two other templates I had used but the problem arose while using the template for the journal "Polymer bulletin" of springer.
The document lokks like the following:

```
\documentclass[lineno,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
Text..........One of such famous compatible exipient is cyclodextrin~\cite{paramera2011stability}.

\bibliographystyle{SPBASIC}
\bibliography{bib file name}

\end{document}
```

Comment: have you run bibtex, what does the bibtex log (`.blg` file) say?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I ran the bibtex file. The following was the output I got

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9) The top-level auxiliary file: sn-article.aux I couldn't open style file sn-basic.bst ---line 17 of file sn-article.aux : \bibstyle{sn-basic : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 155 of file sn-article.aux : \bibstyle : {SPBASIC} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no style file---while reading file sn-article.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited normally"

Comment: well there is the answer: you need to put Springer's `sn-basic.bst`file where bibtex can find it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now, the bibliography list appeared but the citations appear as [?]